# Combining two time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Apologies if this is obviously documented somewhere, but I'm having trouble discovering it.  I have two TimeSeries with some overlapping dates/indices and I'd like to merge them.  I assume I'll have to specify which of the two series to take the values from for the overlapping dates.  For illustration I have:

```
s1:
2008-09-15    100
2008-10-15    101

s2:
2008-10-15    101.01
2008-11-15    102.02
```

and I want:

```
s3:
2008-09-15    100
2008-10-15    101
2008-11-15    102.02
```

or

```
s3:
2008-09-15    100
2008-10-15    101.01
2008-11-15    102.02
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns):

```
In [11]: s1.combine_first(s2)
Out[11]:
2008-09-15    100.00
2008-10-15    101.00
2008-11-15    102.02
dtype: float64
```