# Pandas: apply values from one time series to preceding instances of another

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I have two timeseries (but as DataFrame, i.e. multivariate series), `ts1` and `ts2`. `Ts1` has duplicate times, `ts2` does not. For a given value `ts2[i]` in `ts2`, I'd like to apply that value to the instances in `ts1` that precede `ts2[i]`, but come after `ts2[i-1]`.

Here's an example (univariate for simplicity):

```
ts1:
    t           v
0   2016-03-01  0.676188
1   2016-03-01  0.228074
2   2016-03-04  0.371788
3   2016-03-05  0.802350
4   2016-03-06  0.090599

ts2:
    t           v
0   2016-03-02  1
1   2016-03-05  2
2   2016-03-08  3
```

I'm looking for this outcome:

```
    t           v
0   2016-03-01  1
1   2016-03-01  1
2   2016-03-04  2
3   2016-03-05  2
4   2016-03-06  3
```

Pandas join and merge operations do not exactly achieve what I want. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945166/merging-two-time-series-in-pandas) comes somewhat close, but is not exactly what I want either. It seems this is a pretty basic "time join", so I assumed there should be some out-of-the-box way to do this?

To preclude questions on the duplicate times in ts1: in reality, there is another column (say an ID column) that distinguishes these. So in reality, ts1 could be said to have a MultiIndex. I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible though, and moreover ts2 does *not* have that ID column. I want to apply values purely based on time.

I'm using Python 2.7.x and Pandas 0.17.0. I could probably upgrade the latter if necessary.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then this should work:

```
In [49]:
ts1['v'] = ts2.loc[np.searchsorted(ts2['t'], ts1['t']),'v'].values
ts1

Out[49]:
           t  v
0 2016-03-01  1
1 2016-03-01  1
2 2016-03-04  2
3 2016-03-05  2
4 2016-03-06  3
```

So this uses [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on your 2 datetime Series to return the indices where the ts1['t'] value should be inserted which would be the index position, we then use this to index ts2 and return the 'v' column values, we have to use `.values` here because you have duplicate indices in the returned values so we just want the values without the index:

```
In [51]:
ts2.loc[np.searchsorted(ts2['t'], ts1['t']),'v']

Out[51]:
0    1
0    1
1    2
1    2
2    3
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

You can see that the output from `np.searchsorted` returns the desired index values:

```
In [50]:
np.searchsorted(ts2['t'], ts1['t'])

Out[50]:
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

This assumes that the values are sorted and already `datetime` dtype, if not you can do `ts1['t'] = pd.to_datetime(ts1['t'])`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Pretty straightforward actually...I came up with this solution: 
`ts = ts1.merge(ts2, on='t', how='outer').sort_values(by='t')`
`mask = np.logical_not(ts.v_x.isnull())`
`ts.fillna(method='bfill')[mask]`
But your solution is more elegant.

Comment: I think this suits your requirements as you're specifically looking for the previous row and `np.searchsorted` does that so long as the values are sorted and it's vectorised so it will be fast